# Color list comprehension in Seaborn

Tags: python

```
clrs = [('red' if x=="Male" else 'blue') for x in tips['sex']]
sns.countplot(x='sex',data=tips,palette=clrs)   # count plot
```

[image]

Shouldn't it be'red' for when x=="Male"? But it's filling in that bar with Blue.

Comment: I used that in counterplot - but it's giving the same error

Comment: Figured it out: `sns.countplot(x="sex", data=tips, palette={"Male": "red", "Female": "blue"})`